# How to search mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query from user to search in mysql database

```
<input type="text" name="query_textbox"><input type="submit" name="search_button">
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET['search_button'])) 
   {
    $query = $_GET['query_textbox'];
    $command = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ProteinName` LIKE '%$query%';";
    $result = mysql_query($command);
    echo $result;
   }
?>
```

When I put 'human' in textbox then it works. But when I search for 'human protein' it shows 0 results.
Now the question is "if I search for a query including whitespaces like 'human protein', it should show me result for 'human protein' as well as for 'human' and for 'protein'. How to do that?

Comment: Explode the search query and do a select for every word.

Comment: what engine are you using? Innodb or MyISam?

Comment: @Supericy can you please elaborate? I'm new to both php and mysql

Comment: or try to use wild card with your query that might help

Comment: It may or may not apply in your situation, but there are a few good PHP search engine scripts out there, such as Sphider (which is old)...just a thought.

Comment: @JW.      engine is Innodb

Comment: you can do this by Explode each query and use or condition in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$query = $_GET['query_textbox'];

// explode the query by space (ie "human protein" => "human" + "protein")
$keywords = preg_split("#\s+#", $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// combine the keywords into a string (ie "human" + "protein" => "'%human%' OR '%protein%'")
$condition = "'%" . implode("%' OR '%", $keywords) . "%'";

$command = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ProteinName` LIKE $condition;";
```

Comment: Thnks @Supericy If I want to sort that result on the basis of best matches in descending order. What should I do?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. But I would probably look into something like [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php). But I'm not sure how you could actually implement that.

Comment: I am little surprised that your answer has been upvoted twice. I have tried your suggestion and it didnt worked.

Comment: Try to search with whitespaces and it returns the result of the last element of array.

Comment: @BhavikShah Thanks for letting me know. Should work for varying amounts of white space now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = $_GET['query_textbox'];

// explode the query by space (ie "human protein" => "human" + "protein")
$keywords = explode(" ", $query);

foreach($keywords as $key => $value){
    $condition[] = `ProteinName` LIKE "'%".$value."%'"
}

$cond_str = implode(' OR ', $condition);
$command = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $cond_str;";
```

Comment: Please comment the reason for downvoting the answer.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this 1)gives syntax errors (l. 7); 2) is for a great part copypasted from the accepted answer (of 15 minutes before)

Comment: @DamienPirsy: accepted answer doesnt work. I have tested it. And, with all due respect i would like to ask you, are you sure the author of accepted answer has his own logic and not copy-pasted from somewhere. I really dont mind that someone downvoted my answer. I am not repo-hungry. But i just want to know the reason. I have corrected my answer. Anyways, Thanks for reply.